# Distribution function of sum of two uniformly distributed variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random uniformly distributed variables on $ \{1, 2, \dots,n \}$. And let $Z = X+Y$. Find the PMF of $Z$.

I know that $$ \mathcal{P}(Z=z) = \sum_{x} \mathcal{P}(X=x) \cdot \mathcal{P}(Y=z-x) $$

And i get stuck. I think i have a problem with spliting the sum into ranges where $\mathcal{P}(Y=z-x)$ is $1/n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are implicitly assuming that $\newcommand{\PP}{\mathcal{P}}X$ and $Y$ are independently distributed. Additionally, since the support of $X$ is $\{1,\dots,n\}$, the sum defining $\PP(Z=z)$ ranges from $x=1,\dots, n$ without loss of generality. Then for each $x$ in the range, $\PP(X=x) = \frac{1}{n}$, so the equation reduces to the form
$$
\PP(Z=z)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{x=1}^{n} \PP(Y=z-x).
$$
With that said, it's easiest to break $\PP(Z=z)$ into cases.

*Case 1*: $z < 1$. This never happens because $X, Y \geq 1$. Thus $\PP(Z=z)=0$.

*Case 2*: $1 \leq z \leq n$. Then $\PP(Y=z-x) = \frac{1}{n}$ when $x < z$, which is the case for $x=1,\dots,z-1$. Thus $\PP(Y=z-x) = \frac{z-1}{n}$, and $\PP(Z=z)=\frac{z-1}{n^2}$.

*Case 3*: $n+1\leq z \leq 2n$. Then $\PP(Y=z-x) = \frac{1}{n}$ when $z-n-1 < x$, which happens in the case for $x = z-n,\dots, n$. Thus $\PP(Y=z-x) = \frac{2n+1-z}{n}$, and $\PP(Z=z) = \frac{2n+1-z}{n^2}$.

*Case 4*: $2n < z$. This never happens because $X,Y \leq n$. Thus $\PP(Z=z) = 0$.

The PMF for $Z$ is therefore
$$
\PP(Z=z) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $z < 1$ or $z > 2n$,} \\
\frac{z-1}{n^2} & \text{if $1 \leq z \leq n$,} \\
\frac{2n+1-z}{n^2} & \text{if $n +1 \leq z \leq 2n$.}
\end{cases}
$$